# Merge nested code from xml to xml with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

There is a problem I have. 
I've got first xml:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<groups>
   <group>
      <number>1</number>
   </group>
   <group>
      <number>2</number>
   </group>
   <group>
      <number>3</number>
   </group>
</groups>
```

Using XSLT I want it to be like:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
    <groups>
       <group number="1"/>
       <group number="2"/>
       <group number="3"/>
    </groups>
```

The xslt stylesheet that I'm using right now is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="groups">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="number">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it only deletes "group" field. Need help! 
Thanks in advance

Comment: See: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#creating-attributes and https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#attribute-value-templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with an **identity transform** since the node names and structure in the input and output is quite close. This copies over the input XML as is to the output.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The next step is to convert `<number>` node as an attribute of the `<group>` node. So a template is created to match the `group/number` nodes.

```
<xsl:template match="group/number">
```

Within this template, as mentioned in the comment, an `<xsl:attribute>` will need to be defined. In this case since the attribute name matches the current node name, `local-name()` within `{}` is used. The value of attribute is the value of current `<number>` node.

```
<xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:attribute>
```

Below is the complete XSLT that transforms the input XML into the desired output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
       <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="group/number">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<groups>
    <group number="1" />
    <group number="2" />
    <group number="3" />
</groups>
```

Comment: You are the best! Thank you for such clear explanation!